# What to do with old OS install media?

Tags: installation, operating-systems, media

I'm doing an end-of-the-year clean up and found some old OS install media - Mac OS X 10.3.5, Windows 2000, Windows XP. It seems wrong to just throw them out but they can't have a home with me anymore.

Is there some place I can donate them to?  Anyone know of anyone collecting this stuff for posterity?

Comment: You could send them to me ;)

Answer (score 4):

As long as they are not OEM machine specific install disc, there is always someone out there looking for some old copies of operating systems.  If you want to take the time, you can put them on freecycle, ebay, craigslist for free or you can try and make a couple bucks.

Believe me,  I saw someone the other day that had a collection of AOL cd's on display in their kitchen... so there is **ALWAYS** someone looking for old things. ;)

Answer (score 4):

[Do-It-Yourself Ornaments](http://www.unplggd.com/unplggd/diy-project/old-cds-make-great-holiday-decorations-102412) for that Nonspecific Winter Retail Festival rapidly approaching.

[image]

Comment: That is really hideous! +1!!!

Comment: ain't it just... i've got a rack of 'em drying now.  want one?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like having them lying around, rip them to ISO files and save them to an external hard drive or something, then dispose of the media (or reuse it in an interesting way like ~quack mentioned). Chances are you may want to play with it for nostalgia value some day, then you can easily load it up on a virtual machine from the ISO at any time.

Comment: I used to think that I would get around to playing around with some older stuff some day: I'm wise enough now to realize that it's not going to happen.

Comment: Especially remembering that Win2K doesn't need activation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try selling it on EBay or Craigslist.  I've seen old software on both and there are some who really want it.

They also make great drink coasters.

Comment: note that selling OEM copies may get you into trouble.

Comment: @Molly: Yes, good point. This depends on the jurisdiction, however. In Germany e.g. the Bundesgerichtshof (Supreme Court) ruled that restrictions on OEM software are only binding to the original dealer, not to the customer. So once you legally bought OEM software, you can resell it as you wish. See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Equipment_Manufacturer#OEM-Software . Rules in other countries may be stricter, e.g. because of the DMCA in the United States.

Comment: Good point.  If it is retail media, you can resell it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few organisations who will take and recycle CDs/DVDs

In the UK try [polymerrecycling](http://www.polymerrecycling.co.uk/cd.html), in the US, [cdrecyclingcenter](http://cdrecyclingcenter.com/) or [greendisk](http://www.greendisk.com/) (otherwise Google "cd recycle + location"). But +1 to any interesting reuses first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Keep them or your geek side will hate you!

I have a stack of old CDs that are to be used one day when I have more time!

Comment: Time: always fleeting, never returning.

Comment: +1 not heard that one, but true!